# can I force a closure to be isolated from its parent/outer?

Tags: javascript

Doing some D3 stuff, decided to add a context menu to a pie chart.

```
  // this code may not be complete
  if (!!readOnly) {  
    if (this.link != null) {
      if (d3.select("div#contextMenu").empty()) {
        contextMenu = d3.select(selector).append("div").attr("id", 'contextMenu').attr("class", "rounded");
      }
      d3.selectAll("" + selector + " svg g.slice").on("click", function(object, index) {
        return contextMenu.style("visibility", "hidden");
      }); 
      d3.selectAll("" + selector + " svg g.slice").on("contextmenu", function(object, index) {
        var position;
        if (!contextShowing) {
          position = d3.mouse(this);
          tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
          return contextMenu.style("visibility", "visible");
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

OK now that I've got it working in this graph, I'd like to add it to the other graphs by placing it in their prototype. My first step here is to put all this code in a function, like so:

```
drawContextMenu = function(selector) {
  if (!!readOnly) {  
     // etc...
  } 
};
drawContextMenu(selector);
```

Then I'll move `drawContextMenu` into the prototype once I have the new function working.

In the past when I've done something like this I've gotten a lot of runtime bugs because moving the function into a different closure broke a bunch of variable look ups. So I'm thinking I'd like to make `drawContextMenu` not be able to see its outer closure, if that makes any sense. Like put it into a function that can *only* see variables inside the function. That way I can figure out any broken references before I go moving code around.

Of course I don't have to do it that way but I'm just curious if it's possible. I feel like I just don't know the proper terminology for this or I would've found it already.

Comment: If you don't want it to have access to the variables in the containing function, define it as a named function outside the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the goal is really to take a function and cut it from the scope where it was created, then I don't see other solutions than to take its code and recreate it.

That could be done like this :

```
var a = "some shadowed value";
function outer(){
  var a = "value from normal scope";
  return function(){
    return a;
  }  
}
var child = outer();
console.log(child()); // value from normal scope
var orphan = new Function(child.toString().match(/\{([\w\W]*)\}/m)[1]);
console.log(orphan()); // some shadowed value
```

Of course... This probably shouldn't be done... but as you say you're *"just curious if it's possible"* then this is a valid answer I think ;)

---

Explanation :

- `child.toString()` is the text of the function (`"function(){ some code }"`)
- `/\{([\w\W]*)\}/m` is a regex taking the inside of the brackets ( `"some code"` ) and it's a little tricky because of the multiple lines (hence the `[\w\W]*`)
- `new Function("some code")` creates a new function with the given body

Comment: could you explain what's going on here: `new Function(child.toString().match(/\{([\w\W]*)\}/m)[1]);`?

Comment: Side note : if the function is named and recursive, it logically can call itself. If you want to make an exception for its own name, you could do `var orphan = (new Function('return ('+child.toString()+')'))();`.

Comment: but what I'm really after here is a function that can _only_ see the values that have been passed in to it -- it should get an undefined instead of finding the variable in the outer scope

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that `Function#toString` is not required, even by ES5, to return the source of the function. I think it's on the cards for ES6, but...

Comment: @jcollum then it would be more complicated without a parser. What comes to mind would be 1) parse the function to pick all names 2) declare those names with an undefined value in a specific calling scope

Comment: Another solution could be to pass the text of the function to a webworker and have it create it and execute it...

Answer (score 1):

The usual solution here is a "builder" function to build the callback:

```
// Somewhere nicely contained (not deeply nested)
function createContextMenuRenderer(menu, tt) {
  return function(object, index) {
    var position;
    if (!contextShowing) {
      position = d3.mouse(this);
      tt.style("visibility", "hidden");
      return menu.style("visibility", "visible");
    }
  };
}
```

Then using it:

```
d3.selectAll("" + selector + " svg g.slice").on("contextmenu", createContextMenuRenderer(contextMenu, tooltip));
```

Note that the builder above (`createContextMenuRenderer`) still relies on closing over `d3` and `contextShowing`, but doesn't rely on closing over `contextMenu` or `tooltip`.

Now let's suppose that you want `createContextMenuRenderer` not to close over `contextShowing`, but to *use* whatever the value of `contextShowing` is as of when the `contextmenu` event fires. (We'll still have it close over `d3`.) To do that, you need something that can reach back into the context where you're using the builder:

```
function createContextMenuRenderer(menu, tt, getContextShowing) {
  return function(object, index) {
    var position;
    if (!getContextShowing()) {
      position = d3.mouse(this);
      tt.style("visibility", "hidden");
      return menu.style("visibility", "visible");
    }
  };
}
```

Using it:

```
d3.selectAll("" + selector + " svg g.slice").on("contextmenu",
    createContextMenuRenderer(contextMenu, tooltip, function() {
        return contextShowing;
    })
);
```

`createContextMenuRenderer` is reusable, you just pass a function into it to get the relevant `contextShowing` value.